# Как сделать так, чтобы одинаковые имена не добавлялись в таблицу бд

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

У меня есть база (Номера автомобилей) и я хочу чтобы при добавлении уже существующего номера выходила ошибка, а не добавлялось в таблицу.

Comment: Уникальный индекс на поле номера. И/или проверка на стадии ввода на уровне клиентской части.

Comment: 2-й вариат лучше, только не могу понять как это реализовать

Comment: *как это реализовать* Сделать запрос к таблице на получение записей с введённым номером и проверить, пуст набор записей или нет. Если нет - такая запись уже имеется.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов два:

- проверка в клиентском коде
- использование ограничений на стороне сервера

Реализация на клиенте – возможный вариант, но зачем писать какой-то код, если можно не писать и проверять на сервере? )

Я рекомендую поставить ограничение на стороне сервера.

Для этого в SQL-движках предусмотрен механизм constraint (ограничений).

Вы не пишете, какая конкретно у вас БД - допустим, это MS SQL Server, как наиболее типичный выбор для .net стека.

В SQL Server unique constraint [реализуются](http://www.sql.ru/forum/38556/unique-index-ili-constraint) созданием unique index.

Comment: Даже при наличии проверки в клиенте проверка на сервере все равно должна быть, ибо клиент вы не контролируете. Проверка на клиенте нужна, обычно, лишь для того, чтобы улучшить юзабельность, повысить удобство использования приложением.

Comment: Я написал что использую mdf бд в visualstudio

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, хотелось бы понимать, **чем** вы пользуетесь, в качестве контекста БД в коде.

Как вариант, можете воспользоваться, [LinqToSQL](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/4.1.php):

```
string connectionString = @"ваша строка подключения";

DataContext db = new DataContext(connectionString);

// не обязательно bool, здесь может быть, например, и выброс исключения...
public bool IsExist(string carNumber) 
{
    // не бывает автомобиля без номера (если не притягивать за уши, конечно)
    var car = (from car in db.GetTable<Cars>()
                    where car.LicensePlate == carNumber // licensePlate - номер авто
                    select car).FirstOrDefault();
    if (car == null)
    {
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Или написав параметризированный SQL-запрос на проверку:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.Connection = new SqlConnection("ваша строка подключения");
    command.CommandText = "select LicencePlate from dbo.Cars where dbo.Cars.LicencePlate = @MyPlate";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyPlate", "а777аа"); // пример
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
  // а далее читаете из ридера данные. Если похожих номеров нет, то ридер  вернет null(емнип).
  // Ну и в зависимости от результата уже можно делать инсерт в базу (или нет)
 }
```

UPD. Если Вам необходимо вносить сразу большое количество номеров в БД, то вам действительно нужно посмотреть в сторону SQL Server unique constraint, как верно [указал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824414/283657) @A K. Это удобнее делать на стороне БД.

Comment: бд mdf visualstudio, вывожу базу через datagridview. Ну так только номер a777aa не копируется, а если у меня много номеров

Comment: *.mdf это просто файл базы данных.
`чем вы пользуетесь` - имелось в виду, каким образом пытаетесь получить данные. Через ADO.NET, Entity Framework или другую технологию.
По поводу Вашего вопроса - обновил пост.

Comment: я создал базу в висуал студио

Answer (score 0):

Проверка на стороне сервера:

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTable
 ADD CONSTRAINT UC_ConstraintName UNIQUE (ColumnName);
```