# Как сделать, чтобы одинаковые значения не попали в таблицу MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Например, после регистрации в таблцу попадает следующее [имя1, фамилия1б эмайл1, пароль1].. При следующей регистрации я опять ввел данные где есть [эмайл1]...Как использовать unique, что данные с одинаковыми значениями не попали в таблицу? в Node js..

Comment: повесить на колонку таблицы флаг `UNIQUE` или `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: PRIMARY KEY добавлено на id. а unique?

Comment: A unique добавьте на *эмайл*

Comment: такое уже пробовал, вроде не помогло...

Comment: а нет, помогло, не знаю, почему тогда не получилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В ваше случае самый простой способ, перед вставкой проверять нет ли уже такого значения. Для защиты также добавьте уникальный ключ на поле email

Comment: Пишите более развёрнутые ответы, сейчас пока ничем особо не отличается от уже данных комментариев.

Comment: А ответы уже нужно давать в комментариях? Перенес и оформил ответ в соответствующей политике сайта формате

Comment: Ну вы и сами догадываетесь, что нет. Но вы поди наверное и в курсе, что слишком короткие ответы удаляют и преобразовывают в комментарии. Вот я ваш нашёл как раз в очереди на проверку низкокачественных вопросов. Ну вот например для сравнения тот же самый вопрос вид сбоку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/824405/213987

Comment: "Налито воды" в ответ, чтобы текста было побольше. А суть та же

Comment: Напишите побольше текста и без воды, в чём проблема? У меня был вопрос, в котором было непонятно вообще что за база данных - у вас более конкретный.